# How To Get SUM on SUM

Tags: mysql, sql, database, sum

I tried to use the following SQL query:

```
SELECT p.idproduk, 
       ((p.markp/100)*p.hbproduk) labarugine 
  FROM produk 
  JOIN pesanan o
    ON p.idproduk = o.idproduk
  JOIN penjualan s
    ON o.faktur = s.faktur
```

the result :

```
-------------------------
| idproduk | labarugine |
-------------------------
| 2        | 300        | 
| 2        | 300        |
| 2        | 300        |
| 3        | 400        |
| 3        | 400        |
| 4        | 700        |
-------------------------
```

I want to the result

```
---------------
|  labarugine |
---------------
|  1400       |
---------------
```

Please help me

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to just want `SUM()`.  However, you are only using columns from one table, so this might do what you want:

```
SELECT pr.idproduk, SUM((pr.markp/100)*pr.hbproduk) AS labarugine
FROM produk pr
GROUP BY pr.idproduk
```

In all likelihood, the matches to the other tables are generating duplicates.  If you need the `JOIN`s for filtering, then use `EXISTS` instead:

```
SELECT pr.idproduk, SUM((pr.markp/100)*pr.hbproduk) AS labarugine
FROM produk pr
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM pesanan pe INNER JOIN
                   penjualan pj
                   ON pe.faktur = pj.faktur
              WHERE pr.idproduk = pe.idproduk
             )
GROUP BY pr.idproduk;
```

Comment: Big Thanks Sir i have can finish my problem